# Please help me where are my ether

Tags: myetherwallet

I can't find where is address where it was sent my ether.

TX Hash 0x1407cffd5c1a8dd541b3e9d636d76a9787b52c69239d5564bc0df21020f1a1a8
From Address    0x6Ef6d5Cd57b8f69899D8E4c4BeE71E7B6Cf0487A
To Address  0x72Eb589cD05986C37a4f85D2826C5575ffDB22c3
Amount  1.178278 ETH

I didn't sent from myetherwallet that or it was a mistake.

Thank you,
Andrej

Comment: Are you sure you didn't ? Blockchain says you did. Perhaps your key was not safe and someone transferred the funds without your consent. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your transactions are on Etherscan ([here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6Ef6d5Cd57b8f69899D8E4c4BeE71E7B6Cf0487A)). As you can see, there have been three transactions on the account.

The first one sent money to the account. The other two sent money out of that account to two different addresses.

If you didn't initiate those transfers, then someone definitely has access to your private key because that's the only way money comes out of an account (by signing the transaction with the private key).

**Edit:** Or, as @lungj so kindly points out, the account may be unlocked. I think he's referring to [this](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/29/security-alert-insecurely-configured-geth-can-make-funds-remotely-accessible/), but he will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Transactions can also be initiated if your RPC is open and your accounts are unlocked (so the private key isn't necessarily known by the attacker, but can be used).

Comment: I do not understand how it can be unlocked and everyone has access. What does it mean? It was true that I had access to account with my private key, but only then, and I did not share it with anyone. Can I see if the transfer is made from the same IP or from somwere elsewhere? Is it possible that the recipient's account is on some exchange, like binnance or else? How it is possible to check that?